# How to lag a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, lag

I want to know the command in R to lag a matrix.
I have defined `x` as:

```
> (x <- matrix(1:50, 10, 5))
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50
```

I want create `l.x`:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    NA  NA   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]    1   11   21   31   41
 [3,]    2   12   22   32   42
 [4,]    3   13   23   33   43
 [5,]    4   14   24   34   44
 [6,]    5   15   25   35   45
 [7,]    6   16   26   36   46
 [8,]    7   17   27   37   47
 [9,]    8   18   28   38   48
[10,]    9   19   29   39   49
```

Answer (score 6):

`lag` will coerce your object to a time-series (`ts` class to be specific) and only shifts the time index. It does not change the underlying data.

You need to manually lag the matrix yourself by adding rows of `NA` at the beginning and removing the same number of rows at the end. Here's an example of a function that does just that:

```
lagmatrix <- function(x, k) {
  # ensure 'x' is a matrix
  stopifnot(is.matrix(x))
  if (k == 0)
    return(x)
  na <- matrix(NA, nrow=abs(k), ncol=ncol(x))
  if (k > 0) {
    nr <- nrow(x)
    # prepend NA and remove rows from end
    rbind(na, x[-((nr-k):nr),])
  } else {
    # append NA and remove rows from beginning
    rbind(x[-1:k,], na)
  }
}
```

Or you can use a `lag` function that does what you expect. For example, `xts::lag.xts`.

```
> xts::lag.xts(x)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]    1   11   21   31   41
 [3,]    2   12   22   32   42
 [4,]    3   13   23   33   43
 [5,]    4   14   24   34   44
 [6,]    5   15   25   35   45
 [7,]    6   16   26   36   46
 [8,]    7   17   27   37   47
 [9,]    8   18   28   38   48
[10,]    9   19   29   39   49
> is.matrix(xts::lag.xts(x))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is one manual method in base R with `head` and `rbind`:

```
rbind(NA, head(x, 9))

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]    1   11   21   31   41
 [3,]    2   12   22   32   42
 [4,]    3   13   23   33   43
 [5,]    4   14   24   34   44
 [6,]    5   15   25   35   45
 [7,]    6   16   26   36   46
 [8,]    7   17   27   37   47
 [9,]    8   18   28   38   48
[10,]    9   19   29   39   49
```

More generally, as noted by @akrun, `head(., -1)` will work for any sized matrix:

```
    rbind(NA, head(x, -1))
```

Comment: You could use `rbind(NA, head(x, -1))`.  The method used needs to know the nrow beforehand.

Comment: Really creative solution.

Comment: @lmo I know it's an old answer but I really like it! ;) Would love if we could prepend similarly not just one but N rows of NA.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `apply`

```
library(dplyr)
apply(x, 2, lag)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    1   11   21   31   41
# [3,]    2   12   22   32   42
# [4,]    3   13   23   33   43
# [5,]    4   14   24   34   44
# [6,]    5   15   25   35   45
# [7,]    6   16   26   36   46
# [8,]    7   17   27   37   47
# [9,]    8   18   28   38   48
#[10,]    9   19   29   39   49
```

0r

```
rbind(NA, x[-nrow(x),])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    1   11   21   31   41
# [3,]    2   12   22   32   42
# [4,]    3   13   23   33   43
# [5,]    4   14   24   34   44
# [6,]    5   15   25   35   45
# [7,]    6   16   26   36   46
# [8,]    7   17   27   37   47
# [9,]    8   18   28   38   48
#[10,]    9   19   29   39   49
```

Comment: I assume you have `dplyr` loaded, because your `apply` code will not work with `stats::lag`.  But `dplyr::lag` masks `stats::lag` and treats all inputs as vectors, which is why you need `apply` to loop over columns.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich : Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a pure dplyr solution without the need for apply. Only annoyance here is that it needs to be converted to a data.frame to work.

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%  as.data.frame %>%  mutate_each( funs(lag))
```